# Making a library from an already-existing library

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have noticed that, upon using JFreeChart, the program's size is MUCH bigger (about 1.5 MB) than a standard Java program. To confirm what it might be, I have looked at the official developer's guide to JFreeChart, and noticed that it is more than 900 pages long! This means that using JFreeChart library in Java is like using `system()` in C++ (but much safer). It's like burning your furniture for heat, when there is a good thermostat on the wall. I was wanting to know if it is possible to build a MUCH SMALLER library from the JFreeChart library without having to include everything in the JFreeChart library. In other words, could I simply unpack the executable JAR file, take only the stuff I need for a basic line chart/time chart, and make my own library out of it?

Comment: You could easily use a tool like ProGuard to strip out everything you don't use.

Comment: And, I assume that you can specify what to throw away with this mighty program, too... When I get to my coding computer, I will try this!

Comment: Can you tell ProGuard to keep unused Objects? //I am using polymorphism in my program; I have a master class that starts the whole program in it's constructor

Comment: Sure.  Read http://proguard.sourceforge.net/#manual/examples.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's open source, you can just get the sourcecode, remove all the stuff you don't want or need and recompile/rebuild it into a new light-weight jar. There's probably something like and `ANT` build.xml file in the project that builds it, and you could customize it to suit your needs as well.

If you're open to a trying new charting library that's much more light weight, take a look at [XChart](http://xeiam.com/xchart.jsp). It's open source and actively developed. You can browse the source code or fork the project on [Github](https://github.com/timmolter/XChart). It doesn't have all the features of JFreeChart, but that's fine in many cases.

Comment: This would require modifying all the `.class` files in all the target libraries used by your program, right?

Comment: I have tried unzipping the original JAR library to a folder, going through the folder, removing everything that I didn't import, rebuilding the JAR from what's left (what I actually included), casted it to `newLibrary.jar`, and just including this newLibrary.jar just like I included the original. The problem is, it doesn't recognize ANY of the imports that are dependent on this newLibrary! What could I possibly be doing wrong? Would I need to modify the `.class` files, just to be safe?

Comment: You're going about it wrong. You need to first get the source code, which is a collection of *.java files, which you can apparently get [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/jfreechart/code/HEAD/tree/). Then you need to remove the *.java files you don't need. Finally you need to compile these files and package them into a jar. The compiled files will have the .class extension. Doing this is no trivial task, but it can be done.